# UPDATE Multiple records in MySQL from JavaFX after checkout in Cart

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update

I am having a cart page where users can checkout after purchasing the products/medicines. I am having a button named checkout on that page. After clicking that button "CheckOut" I want to update multiple records in MySQL from JavaFX after clicking that button. I want the quantity of each item/medicine in the tableView to decreased according to the quantity purchased. I have tried putting the query in for loop I tried to selectAll from the table view. I will provide the code I wrote and a screenshot from the JavaFX tableView with the buttons. Any help is appreciated. Thanks for your time and cooperation from now.

```
package Patient;

import Admin.Doctor.AddDoctor;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;


import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import static Admin.AdminLogin.rightDown;
import static Connection.DBConnection.*;
import static sample.ChoicePage.scene;

public class CompletePurchase
{
    private StackPane tablePane;
    private TableView<Cart> cartTableView;

    private JFXButton remove;
    private JFXButton complete;

    public void complete()
    {
        rightDown.getChildren().clear();

        new AddDoctor().back();

        tablePane = new StackPane();
        tablePane.setMinWidth(700);
        tablePane.setMinHeight(500);
        tablePane.setLayoutY(90);
        tablePane.setLayoutX(150);

        tablePane.getChildren().clear();

        remove = new JFXButton("REMOVE");
        remove.setPrefWidth(200);
        remove.setPrefHeight(35);
        remove.setLayoutX(300);
        remove.setLayoutY(600);
        remove.getStyleClass().add("loginButton");
        remove.setOnAction((e)->{
            try
            {
                Cart cart = cartTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

                String removeQuery = "DELETE FROM Cart WHERE MedicineID = ?";
                preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(removeQuery);
                preparedStatement.setString(1,cart.getMedicineID());
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                preparedStatement.close();

                cartTableView.getItems().removeAll(cartTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
            }
            catch(Exception e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        rightDown.getChildren().add(remove);

        complete = new JFXButton("CHECKOUT");
        complete.setPrefWidth(200);
        complete.setPrefHeight(35);
        complete.setLayoutX(600);
        complete.setLayoutY(600);
        complete.getStyleClass().add("loginButton");
        complete.setOnAction((e)->{
            try
            {
                cartTableView.getSelectionModel().selectAll();
                int num = cartTableView.getItems().size();
                Cart cart = cartTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

                String updateQuery = "UPDATE Medicine SET Quantity = Quantity - ? WHERE MedicineID = ?";
                preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(updateQuery);
                preparedStatement.setString(1,cart.getQuantity());
                preparedStatement.setString(2,cart.getMedicineID());

                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                preparedStatement.close();
            }

            catch(Exception e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        rightDown.getChildren().add(complete);

        ObservableList<Cart> cartObservableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        TableColumn<Cart,String> PatientID = new TableColumn<>("PATIENT ID");
        PatientID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("PatientID"));
        PatientID.setPrefWidth(116);

        TableColumn<Cart,String> MedicineID = new TableColumn<>("MEDICINE ID");
        MedicineID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("MedicineID"));
        MedicineID.setPrefWidth(116);

        TableColumn<Cart,String> MedicineName = new TableColumn<>("MEDICINE NAME");
        MedicineName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("MedicineName"));
        MedicineName.setPrefWidth(116);

        TableColumn<Cart,String> Price = new TableColumn<>("PRICE");
        Price.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Price"));
        Price.setPrefWidth(116);

        TableColumn<Cart,String> Quantity = new TableColumn<>("QUANTITY");
        Quantity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Quantity"));
        Quantity.setPrefWidth(116);

        TableColumn<Cart,String> TotalPrice = new TableColumn<>("TOTAL PRICE");
        TotalPrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("TotalPrice"));
        TotalPrice.setPrefWidth(116);

        try
        {
            resultSet = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Cart");

            while (resultSet.next())
            {
                cartObservableList.add(new Cart(
                        resultSet.getString("PatientID"),
                        resultSet.getString("MedicineID"),
                        resultSet.getString("MedicineName"),
                        resultSet.getString("Price"),
                        resultSet.getString("Quantity"),
                        resultSet.getString("TotalPrice")
                ));
            }
        }

        catch(Exception e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        cartTableView = new TableView<>();
        cartTableView.getColumns().addAll(PatientID,MedicineID,MedicineName,Price,Quantity,TotalPrice);
        cartTableView.setItems(cartObservableList);
        cartTableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(
                SelectionMode.MULTIPLE
        );

        cartTableView.setMinWidth(700);
        cartTableView.setMinHeight(500);
        cartTableView.setLayoutY(0);
        cartTableView.setLayoutX(0);

        tablePane.getChildren().add(cartTableView);
        rightDown.getChildren().addAll(tablePane);

        scene.getStylesheets().add("Admin/Doctor/AddDoctor.css");
    }
}
```

SCREENSHOT FROM THE CART
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since You are using `PreparedStatement`
So you can use the addBatch() method, which internally stores all the queries and executes them combinedly rather executing one by one as you have done in the loop.

Further, it is good to use transactions here.
You can use appropriate `begin transaction` command in the begining of the batch, then add all the relevant queries, here in your case UPDATE QUERIES, then lastly add `commit command`
and then execute it. For any kind of error, all the updates will be rolled back and in case of successful updates, your queries will be executed at once and you don't need to use any loops for executing query one - by - one

Here is an article
[PreparedStatememt Batchs](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/batchupdate.html)

Check this heading `PreparedStatement Batch Updates`

Hope you problem gets solved at the earliest.

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Really thank you very much for your help man much appreciated.